# Oracle Query with dates

Tags: oracle, date

This query:

```
SELECT
Min(DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Date")
FROM
DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR
WHERE
DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Week" = 8
```

returns 13-02-18 00:00:00

this query:

```
SELECT
Min(DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Date")
FROM
DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR
WHERE
DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Week" = 9
```

returns 13-02-25 00:00:00

The following uses the first 2 queries and of course DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN is not empty.
So why is this returning 0 rows?

```
SELECT
...
...
FROM
DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN
INNER JOIN DB_SAM.T_ZELLEN ON DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN."Ort" = DB_SAM.T_ZELLEN."Betriebsstelle"
WHERE
DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN."Stg Beginn" >= (SELECT Min(DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Date") FROM DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR WHERE DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Week" = 8) AND
DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN."Stg Beginn" < (SELECT Min(DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Date") FROM DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR WHERE DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Week" = 9)
```

btw. these conditions are working:

```
WHERE
DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN."Stg Beginn" >= TO_DATE('02/18/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') AND
DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN."Stg Beginn" < TO_DATE('02/25/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: because table DB_SAM.T_MELDUNGEN is empty? because you check DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Week" = 6 instead of 8? because you miss information? you could show sample data or remove one condition after an other to check which is it

Comment: You present query A and then ask why query B does a totally different thing. Why? Because it's not the same query.

Comment: Does `SELECT to_char(Min(DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Date"), 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR WHERE DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Week" = 8` show the year as 2013, or 1913 (for example); and the same for week 9?

Comment: Thanks Alex Poole. This showed as 0013.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT to_char(Min(DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Date"), 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR WHERE DB_SAM.T_CALENDAR."Week" = 8` showed the year as 0013.